Degree of inverse of f in NTRU?
In NTRU, we know that $f$ is a ternary polynomial in the ring $$R=\frac{\mathbb{Z}_q[x]}{x^n-1}.$$
Here $f$ has $d+1$ coefficients 1 and $d$ coefficients $-1$ and rest are zero.
For computing the public key, it is known that $$h=f^{-1}g$$ where $g$ is also a ternary polynomial with $d$ coefficients 1 and $d$ coefficients $-1$ and rest are zero.
Is there any result that informs about the possible degrees of $f^{-1}$? My main doubt is what if it is small enough?

We would typically calculate $f^{-1}$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm, so that it has degree at most $n-1$ and typically has degree exactly $n-1$.

How it would typically be $n-1$?

@PAMG Because more than a proportion $(q-1)/q$ of elements of $R^*$ have degree $n-1$.

Can you please explain it how?

@PAMG balls and bins probability! There are possible $q$ balls one can put into the bin ( the $n-1$ degree monomial) of which one is zero. Zero makes, a degree not equal to $n-1$. Now clear?

Yes. Thank you.
